# How can I retrieve a lot of results in Hbase (like a IN in SQL)

Tags: hbase

I store in my database price and stocks from products (timeseries).
my rowkey has the following structure:

productid-timestamp

with the families stock, price and so on.

It is possible to get in a scan more than 1 product-id?

for example: give me all data from product-id 4711, 4744, 8485, 8585 ... without more than one call.

Regards
Kevin

Comment: Timestamp as rowkey?It's gonna hit you after sometime.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a new enough HBase version you can use the HTable [batch method](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/HTable.html#batch%28java.util.List%29) to get several ids in one call

Answer (score 0):

HBase has two fundamental retrieval options: GET and SCAN. A SCAN means: start at row N, and return all records sequentially until you hit row M (where M >= N). A GET is just a single-row scan (M==N); in fact, it's actually implemented as such, which makes sense because the rows are sorted, so there's no fundamentally more efficient way to get to one of them.

So, for your case, you have a few options:

1. You can just get each one with a single GET call, which incurs RPC overhead each time.
2. You can get many of them with a single [batch](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/HTable.html#batch%28java.util.List%29) call, which incurs only one RPC (per region, if your rows lie across multiple regions; and limited by the batch size, if you're getting lots of them). This is a clear win over #1 for your case, it would seem.
3. If your rows lie clustered in a small space of the row key, you could alternately manually assemble them into multiple scans to be run in parallel and then do post-filtering on the client side to just return the ones you want (in your case, you could scan from 4711->4744, and from 8485->8585). This requires a lot more smarts to get right, but might win in some sheer performance scenarios depending on the sparseness or density of the table, the row sizes, etc. You could probably only determine this by
4. You could use a custom filter with [SEEK_NEXT_USING_HINT](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/Filter.ReturnCode.html#SEEK_NEXT_USING_HINT) to save raw scan time in a case like this, by doing a "skip scan" where once you see you've passed the end of one cluster of desired IDs, you jump forward to the next one. Again, depending on the characteristics of the table, this may or may not be a win.

There's also one other nice option: you could use [Phoenix](https://github.com/forcedotcom/Phoenix), a SQL skin on top of HBase. It's got Skip Scans already built in for exactly this case, and is exposed as a JDBC driver. It also has lots of other performance optimizations that would be laborious to create from scratch (aggregation coprocessors, etc).

(Full disclosure, I work for the company that created Phoenix, but it's fully open source so I don't have any particular vested interest in suggesting it, other than thinking it's cool. :)